# Turing machine: w contains twice as many 0s as 1s

Tags: turing-machines

Having this, if I pass an empty input to the machine it is supposed to be accepted, isn't it? It doesn't say 'exactly'.

Comment: Where did you encounter this task?  Have you asked whoever set the task?  Can you quote the exact words, and credit the original source?

Comment: Zero *is* exactly twice zero. Outside of formal contexts, I see *about* as well as *at least* as alternative, if less likely, interpretations.

Comment: Your question is likely to be closed if no clarification is given.